# uploading an image to Amazon S3 using AWS PreSignedURL

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am generating presigned URL with HttpVerb as PUT to upload file to my bucket.
Strange thing is that when I am using AWSDK to upload file using preseigned URL  then it is working fine. But when I am using this URL in the form action method then I am getting the below error.
**"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."**

Below is the HTML code to upload the file

```
    <html> 
  <head>
    <title>S3 POST Form</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body> 
    <form action="https://mvrskt-certifications.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/Temp/ARMA.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIGPD33Q3DT22IFWQ&Expires=1451482258&Signature=nYx%2F2kDmna5XqEWx5CPTg4OIYDU%3D" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="key" value="mvrskt-certifications/Temp/ARMA.jpg">
      <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg">
      <!-- Include any additional input fields here -->

      File to upload to S3: 
      <input name="file" type="file"> 
      <br> 
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File to S3"> 
    </form> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is the C#.NET code which I am using to generate the PreSignedURL

```
GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key        = objectKey,
                    Verb       = HttpVerb.PUT,
                    Expires    = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15)
                };

            string url = null;
           request.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            url = s3Client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
```

I have set CORS policy on my bucket as mentioned below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I am new to AWS S3 and getting totally confuse on using this....
pl assist on how to upload this file using form post OR AJAX

**Morever do we need to generate the PreSignedURL for each image which I am going to upload?**

I can see that we can use signed policy also to upload the images but do I need to generate the signed policy for each image which I am going to upload

Comment: Could you post your solution as how you endedup solving this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pre-signed URL is specific to the key (path/file in the bucket), the HTTP verb (`PUT`), and other attributes of the request you're going to make.

A form `POST` is not an HTTP `PUT` request, so that is the simple explanation of why you can't use a pre-signed URL for a `PUT` request when you're making a `POST`.

Not only are the verbs not interchangeable, a browser-based `POST` upload is an entirely different operation than `PUT`, and requires the signed policy statement to indicate the acceptable values for the various form fields.  You can't upload from a form without that.

Yes, you should generate the policy and signature for each file you want to upload, otherwise you expose yourself to a malicious user overwriting a file other than the one you intended for them to be able to write.